# Chrome Only ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: nginx, ssl, openssl, ubuntu-14.04, tls1.2

One of the sites I manage started having a problem recently where if you try to access it via chrome (and apperently opera, and new edge) I get the ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR error page. And unfortunantly there is not further information I have been able to find about what the underlying error actually is.

All of the suggestions elsewhere list things wrong on the client side except server clock skew - which existed but was fixed with no effect on the error.

running `echo | openssl s_client -servername <site_url> -connect <site_url>:443` on mac gives a successful tlsv1.2 response.

running `https https://<site_url>` gives a successful HTTP response.

The site works in IE11, Firefox, Edge (old) as well as with openssl commandline.

The site is wordpress running on Ubuntu 14.04 (openssl version 1.0.1f) with PHP 5.6 and nginx 1.6.2

As I said above - I have already corrected the ~3 minute clock skew on the server that could cause ssl failure.

Any help is appreciated.

--Update--

I get the following protocol vulnuablities when checking on [SSLLab](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/)
[SSL labs protocol section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbFfU.png)

Comment: This is unlikely to have something to do with clock skew. Please check the site with [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html). If there is nothing obvious wrong you probably need to actually provide the URL so that others can try to reproduce your problem to better understand it - because the current details are not sufficient to narrow down the problem. Also note that Ubuntu 14.04 is out of support for over a year now.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich thanks for pointing me to SSLLabs, I had heard of it before but forgot it existed. It looks like the version of OpenSSL on the server (1.0.1f) is susceptible to a padding oracle attack as well as OpenSSL 0-length attack, and it gets an F score (with a 0 on the protocol support metric). The only simulated handshake that failed was for Chrome 49 on XP SP3.

Comment: There is no obvious problem with the portion of the results you show from SSLLabs. If you need help you likely need to provide the actual domain in question so that others can reproduce the problem and dig deeper for a solution.